# Alterar tamanho da fonte usando @Html.Label

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Como eu faço para atribuir um tamanho de fonte e cores usando `@Html.Label`?

Sei que se eu usar o htmlAttributes posso usar: `@class = ...` eu consigo via css. Mas gostaria de poder fazê-lo sem o uso de CSS. Tem como?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.Label("MeuLabel", new { @style = "color: #000000" })
```

Só preencher o `@style` com o estilo CSS que desejar.

Comment: Agora sem o uso do css não é possível, certo?

Comment: Certo. Antigamente tinha umas tags HTML que era possível especificar isso, mas elas foram depreciadas. Hoje em dia são fora do padrão.